# 2 Questions concerning the JSSOR-Slider

Tags: jssor

First of all I have to say:

what a phantastic piece of software!

Well designed, implemented and documented, and many, many cool features.

Tanks a lot for giving that away as Open Source!

Now I have made a slider implementation for the "Gambio GX"-shopsystem (a **very** advanced osCommerce fork.)

You can see it here in action: http://marmorkamin-shop.de/Test/

I have used **all** image transformations (377) and caption animations (438) available, both are randomly selected for each slide...

(Resulting in 163,618(!) different ways to change slides....)

The slider is dynamically generated with PHP, based on slide-information in the shops database....

As inline-styles are very inflexible in such an environment, I have moved the styling to a stylesheet.

It already works like a charm, almost....

Two problems I am encountering:

The caption area is sometimes clipped
(see 1st caption in this picture: [screenshot](http://www11.pic-upload.de/20.07.14/3mte9512xyr.jpg))

Only bullets 1, 2 and 3 in the bullet navigator are active, the others do not respond.

Any idea what could be the reason for this??

Thx again for this great software!

Edit:

> The caption area is sometimes clipped (see 1st caption in this
>   picture: screenshot)

Found a quick and dirty solution for this meanwhile:

Assign a `clip: auto !important;` CSS direktice for the caption elements...

But I am sure there must be a better solution :-)

Answer (score 0):

Re: caption clipped
Please always specify width and height for caption.
You can specify width and height in css file,

```
.slide_caption_1 {
    left: 100px; top: 200px; width: 110px; height: 29px;
}
.slide_caption_2 {
    left: 150px; top: 250px; width: 110px; height: 29px;
}
.slide_caption_3 {
    left: 200px; top: 300px; width: 110px; height: 29px;
}
```

And you can specify inline style as well,

```
<div class="jssor_slide_caption slide_caption_1" data-u="caption" t="*" style="width: 110px; height: 30px;"></div>
```

Re: bullet problem
Style for 'mousedown' of bullet navigator not specified.
Given class of navigator item prototype is 'jssor_navigator_entry', the class name for 'active' state is 'jssor_navigator_entryav', the class name for 'mousedown' state is 'jssor_navigator_entrydn'
So, please add following css code in slideshow.css file.

```
.jssor_navigator_entrydn {
    padding: 5px 0px 0px; border: currentColor; border-image: none; width: 27px; height: 24px; text-align: center; color: white !important; font-weight: bold !important; text-decoration: none; margin-right: 0px; float: left; display: block; position: relative !important; z-index: 9; cursor: pointer; background-color: rgb(50, 22, 1);
}
```

Comment: Thx for the answer.

Its is virtually impossible to specify a fixed width for the captions, as they are of different length...

On the other hand, the entries also posess the class "jssor_slide_caption", which specifies width and height as "auto".

What is astonishing also in the context is, that many times the captions are correct.

So I stick to my CSS solution, which prevents "clipping" on these items.

jssor_slide_caption

Comment: Calculation of animation depends on width and height. It may set clip, transform, top, left attribute from time to time to play the animation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to define bullet navigator in a simple way,

```
<script>
    var jssor_options={
      ...
      $BulletNavigatorOptions: {                        //[Optional] Options to specify and enable navigator or not
        ...
        $SpacingX: 5,                                   //[Optional] Horizontal space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
        ...
      }
      ...
    };
<script>

<!-- Bullet Navigator Begin -->
<style>
    .the_navigator{
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0px;
    }

    .the_navigator_item, .the_navigator_itemdn, .the_navigator_itemav {
        position: absolute;
        width: 27px;
        height: 24px;
        line-height: 24px;
        color: #fff;
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: #321601;
        text-align: center;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .the_navigator_item:hover, .the_navigator_itemav {
        background-color: #d1013f;
    }
</style>
<!-- bullet navigator container -->
<div class="the_navigator" data-u="navigator">
    <!-- bullet navigator item prototype -->
    <div class="the_navigator_item" data-u="prototype"><numbertemplate></numbertemplate></div>
</div>
<!-- Bullet Navigator End -->
```